# How to link javascript file to java.awt.Canvas?

Tags: java, javascript, canvas, scriptengine

I have an object of java.awt.Canvas and a javascript file canvas.js

canvas.js contains:

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,150,75);
```

Then the canvas.js is loaded to ScriptEngine by:

```
ScriptEngine se = new LoadEnabledRhinoEngineFactory().getScriptEngine();
try {
    se.eval("loadScript('/home/ani/canvas.js');");
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Now I want canvas.js to draw on java.awt.Canvas object. Is it possible, if yes then how if not what is the alternative?

Comment: The alternative is drawing directly to the java.awt.Canvas. I frankly doubt that what you want is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Highly doubt that canvas.js can draw on java.awt.Canvas. [Here is an alternative](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/ui/ex/PaintArea.java)